# Present or past when the thing doesn't exist

Tags: past-tense

A: Did you ever have the orange sherbet at Johnny's Icecream Shop? It's a shame the place burned down and no longer exists.

B: I used to. All the time. I **liked** that a lot. What a pity.

Would it be possible to use **like** instead of **liked** because even it is something he won't be able to do anymore and belongs to the past, he probably still like it at the time of speaking and will continue to like it

Comment: But he doesn't still like it at the time of speaking about it. As you say, it no longer exists. He can still like *the memory* of it, but the orange sherbet can only be something that he *liked*.

Comment: that was  what i thought but (was not sure 100% sure) thanks for confirming

Answer (score 2):

You must use like**d**, because the place no longer exist:

> I used to. All the time. I **liked** that a lot. What a pity.